# Find element with compound class in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I can see some posts about this topic but unfortunately, none worked in my case. I am trying to locate elements with compounded classes in its name. This is the name of the elements class:

```
class="group-header__wrapper is-grid-view-active section--prematch markets-optimized--3"
```

I tried with this line of code, which is not working:

```
containers = SBdriver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".group-header.wrapper.is-grid-view-active.section.prematch.markets-optimized--3")
```

Am I right to assume the class consists of 3 other classes or there are more? This is my entire code so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
from os import pardir
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import BaseWebElement
from googletrans import Translator
import time
import schedule

SB_datalist = []

SBdriver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/tmarkac/source/repos/chromedriver.exe')
superbet_ufootball_url= 'https://superbet.pl/zaklady-bukmacherskie/pilka-nozna'
SBdriver.get(superbet_ufootball_url)
SBdriver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
containers = SBdriver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".group-header__wrapper.is-grid-view-active.section--prematch.markets-optimized--3")
SB_datalist.append(containers)
print("Cont: ",SB_datalist)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Tested your code and you can select the elements you want with this...

`SBdriver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".group-header__wrapper.section--prematch.markets-optimized--3")`

---

you need it constructed like this

```
.group-header__wrapper.is-grid-view-active.section--prematch.markets-optimized--3
```

you have a .  where the __ is but that is incorrect that is one class name

`group-header__wrapper`

Comment: Tried pasting your snippet but still not getting what I want so I will rewrite my initial post and put the entire code if someone wants to test it itself. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Lewis. How did you know you could drop this part: is-grid-view-active?

Comment: When I navigated to the site and inspected the element it did not have this class anywhere on the page.  I assume that its a class for displaying a visual clue that the specific element is "active" or "focused" and when using selenium I assume you are not focusing that element so the class doesn't get added.

Comment: Side note - betting is always a fruitless task, the bank always wins. But you do you, glad it helped.

Comment: Appreciate it mate, actually working for a sports betting operator and needed help with some analysis.

Comment: @JapoJapic must be an easier way to access the data, api etc

Comment: Yeah,mate I hear you but I just started with coding so happy with what I acomplished with your help. But APIs are next thing on my list